# Webforms - Integrating conditional fields into select options

Tags: webforms, entities

I'm looking for a way to have fields show up if a user selects a particular option, inline with, or directly below the option.

For example:

- I would like to teach (if selected show a list of grades directly below or inline with question).
- I would like to mentor (if selected show a list of grades directly below or inline with question).
- I would like to supervise (if selected show a list of grades directly below or inline with question).

I've tried to do it using conditionals, but it can only show fields at the end of all of the select options.